# where can I find these rpm packages?

Tags: linux, unix, glibc

I have to install these two packages but couldn't find then anywhere

```
glibc-32bit-8.1-9
glibc-devel-32bit-8.1-9
```

Could you please help in locating them?

Comment: Which flavour Linux are you using?

Comment: Smells like SLES.

Comment: I am using RHEL5 ( Redhat Ent Linux)

Comment: Try asking on Super User. Also, glibc is not the same as glib, I removed the tag.

Answer (score 1):

RH-derived products are multilib, which means that you're looking for `glibc.i?86` and `glibc-devel.i?86`. Multiple packages may match that; pick the ones with the highest number.

Answer (score 0):

you can try in package manager repository.If you are using ubuntu you can try

```
sudo aptitude search glibc
```

it should show the available package which you can directly install.

Comment: He is looking for RPMs, which Ubuntu doesn't use…